# NServiceBus 4.03 Removing worker node

Tags: nservicebus, nservicebus-distributor, nservicebus4

We have blue/green deployment process where we want to remove couple of workers. How do I remove the worker messages stored in the storage q?. We have got a work around of emptying the storage q.

Does NServiceBus give out of the box way of doing it?

Comment: Is this running in a virtualized environment?

Comment: Yes, it is in virtualized env

Answer (score 0):

There is no current OOTB support for doing this in V4. It's on the roadmap for future versions.

In the meantime...

1. Shut down the worker node.
2. Because of those messages in the storage queue, the distributor will think the worker is ready for more work, so wait for it to assign more work to the decommissioned worker's queue.
3. If that's too long to wait, clear the master's storage queue, then restart all the other workers so they resend their ReadyMessages to the distributor.